# Activity class {com.android.co.smash/com.android.smash.views.activities.LoginActivity} does not exist

Tags: android, package

I have changed the package name from: **com.android.co.smash** 
to: **com.android.smash**

but after changing the name is shows error:

com.android.co.smash/com.android.smash.views.activities.LoginActivity} does not exist.

it seems like the old name still exist, how can i solve this problem?

Comment: how did you changed the package name ?

Comment: Did you followed these steps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem when uninstalling the app and then trying to run it again from Android Studio. There seems to be some kind of bug where it thinks there is already a version of your app installed. Very weird. On your device, if you go into Settings > Apps & notifications > Your app, (If you have deleted the app) you will see all the options greyed out. In the top right corner click the 3 dots for the more options menu, then click Uninstall for all users. This will remove whatever remnants of your app are left on the device. Then you should be able to run it from Android Studio again without any issues.